# Apple calendar: "Your event couldn't be refreshed" Error

Tags: calendar

I'm using the built-in Apple Calendar app on my M2 MacBook Pro & iPhone 14. I like the idea that all calendars can synchronize. I have two google calendars linked, as well as one calendar from my startup which uses Zoho for their mail and calendar application. For the Zoho account, I sometimes receive an error message:

[image: Error message]

But when you click on the error message, it doesn't let you know what event can't be refreshed. Is there a way to see some kind of error log or further details? I'll just go ahead and delete this calendar event if I have to.

I saw some posts that say to clear out the CalDav connection, delete it, and start over. That seems like a strange workaround where there is something that is causing an issue. I want to find out what the issue is so I can resolve it. This is not the first time I ran across this issue (as I have gone ahead and removed the account from my laptop and re-added it and it worked for a while and now it is occurring again).

I posted to Apple forums but received no responses.